# How to I add code into <script> </script>

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add code into script but it just doesnt work

```
    var script= document.createElement('script');
    script.type= 'text/javascript';
    script.textContent = var Module = {
        TOTAL_MEMORY: 536870912,
        errorhandler: null, 
        compatibilitycheck: null,
        dataUrl: "Release/Arctopia_Path_Monopoly_v1.1.1GL.data",
        codeUrl: "Release/Arctopia_Path_Monopoly_v1.1.1GL.js",
        memUrl: "Release/Arctopia_Path_Monopoly_v1.1.1GL.mem",
    };
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
```

How do i add to become like this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way; escaping the double quotes (enclose the inner content with `"`) and vice versa. Another way is to use an array to make your code readable and join them using `.join()`

```js
    var script= document.createElement('script');
    script.type= 'text/javascript';
    script.textContent = 'var Module = { TOTAL_MEMORY: 536870912, errorhandler: null, compatibilitycheck: null, dataUrl: "Release/Arctopia_Path_Monopoly_v1.1.1GL.data", codeUrl: "Release/Arctopia_Path_Monopoly_v1.1.1GL.js", memUrl: "Release/Arctopia_Path_Monopoly_v1.1.1GL.mem", };';
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Using array:

```js
var script= document.createElement('script');
    
    scriptContent = ['var Module = {',
        'TOTAL_MEMORY: 536870912,',
        'errorhandler: null,',
        'compatibilitycheck: null,',
        'dataUrl: "Release/Arctopia_Path_Monopoly_v1.1.1GL.data",',
        'codeUrl: "Release/Arctopia_Path_Monopoly_v1.1.1GL.js",',
        'memUrl: "Release/Arctopia_Path_Monopoly_v1.1.1GL.mem",',
    '};',
    'console.log(Module)'].join("");

    script.type= 'text/javascript';
    script.textContent = scriptContent;
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write your code like this:

```
<script>
  // your javascript code
</script>
```

Or make another JavaScript file, eg. "main.js", and then load it in your HTML right before the end of body:

```
<script src="location/of/main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers allow

```
script.textContent = `var Module = {
    TOTAL_MEMORY: 536870912,
    errorhandler: null, 
    compatibilitycheck: null,
    dataUrl: "Release/Arctopia_Path_Monopoly_v1.1.1GL.data",
    codeUrl: "Release/Arctopia_Path_Monopoly_v1.1.1GL.js",
    memUrl: "Release/Arctopia_Path_Monopoly_v1.1.1GL.mem",
};`;
```